# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - S, Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, runtime

Here is method that replaces all spaces in a string with '%20'. It works fine in general, but complains when execution finishes with 'Run-Time Check Failure #2 - S'. Is there an issue with my for loop?

```
void replaceSpace(char *s) {
    int spaces = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        if (s[i] == ' ') {
            spaces++;
        }
    }

    // new string that includes overwriting space, and two additional chars
    int newLen = strlen(s) + spaces * 2;

    s[newLen] = '\0';
    for (int i = strlen(s) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (s[i] == ' ') {
            s[newLen - 1] = '0';
            s[newLen - 2] = '2';
            s[newLen - 3] = '%';
            newLen -= 3;
        }
        else {
            s[newLen - 1] = s[i];
            --newLen;
        }
    }
}




char test[] = "rep lace Spac e";
replaceSpace(test);
cout << test << endl; //rep%20lace%20Spac%20e
```

edit: I ran this through [cpp shell](http://cpp.sh/) and did not have any issues oddly. Ill try updating visual studio 2015, and report back.

edit2: Nope, same error.

Comment: *Seemingly* working is one of the possibilities of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

When you define `test`

```
char test[] = "rep lace Spac e";
```

you define an array of *exactly* 16 characters (don't forget the string terminator). There is no way to expand the array, meaning you will write out of bounds of the array which leads to *undefined behavior*.

The solution, of course, is to use `std::string` instead, and *append* to it.

Comment: Is there really no other way around it? The implementation in java seemed to have no issue. I can of course simply use the std::replace, but I am practicing implementation.

Comment: @mannerofallthings Arrays have a fixed size, that's it. If you want to extend the string (like replacing one character with three) then you need some kind of dynamic data structure, like the standard `std::string` class.

Answer (score 0):

Really, this code is not necessary. Check it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string s("rep lace Spac e");
    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::isspace)), s.end());
    std::cout << s;
}
```

Comment: Needs explanation of how and why this works otherwise you are simply promoting [Cargo Cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)

Comment: OP wants all spaces replaced by "%20", not simply deleted.